# iRedMail - Unable to send to alias from outside domain, even with accesspolicy set to "public"

Tags: gmail, iredmail

I have setup the latest version of iRedMail on an Ubuntu 22.04 machine, and have setup an alias and forwarding by directly adding records in the `alias` and `forwarding` tables in the vmail database. I have set accesspolicy to "public" for the alias. I am able to send mails to the alias from within the domain, from accounts in the same domain. But I'm unable to send mail to this alias from outside the domain, from Gmail for instance. I don't see any records of attempts to send mail in the logs on the system. But the message I get when attempting to send a mail to this alias from Gmail is:

```
The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect. 
Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7720 
[mydomain.com xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: timed out]
```

I'm able to send and receive email to Gmail ids otherwise. Anyone know what the problem might be and how to troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 0):

I got a response from someone on the iredmail forum. The reason this was happening was because port 25 was being blocked. Opening port 25 on the firewall, fixed the issue. Not sure why regular emails don't require port 25, but only emails to aliases require port 25 but there it is.